# How to get rid of spider mites on roses?

Tags: roses, spider-mites

My girlfriend got a rose to sprout and then planted. It grew nicely but now spider mites are coming back all the time.
She tried a BAYER spray for mite control but they are coming back every time she has the rose plant inside the house.

Answer (score 6):

Either soap and water applied at 5 to 6 days intervals with particular attention being paid to get good coverage on the underside of the leaves or keeping the rose outside would solve this problem.  [This answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/1842/51) is very detailed; I recommend looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

In the growing season you need to use insecticidal soap mixed with pyrethrin.This will kill the mites without harming the roses. At our nursery, we have the same exact problem and that's the only solution that will work effectively without hampering the growth and over all health of your rose bushes.

Comment: There is no need to add pyrethrin to kill spider mites for one plant.  For a nursery with hundreds of plants a pyrethrin is a good choice but overkill for a homeowner