# What is this small red/green leaf plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

What is this plant called, and what height do they grow to? I've had it for 3 years and the roots are growing out the bottom of the pot. I normally water every few days, seems to grow well either in sunshine or shade. Should I replant into a bigger pot?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site Emma! Thanks for sharing this question. It looks like a previous one is very similar though, and it has answers with detailed information, so yours might be closed as a [duplicate](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). Check it out and if you don't find what you need there, feel free to edit your question to show how it's different. Leave us a comment here if you need help with anything. This is a great place and we hope you’ll hang around so we can get to know you and your gardening needs!

Answer (score 3):

This plant is [Dracaena Marginata](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=b592), also called the dragon tree.  It has thick fleshy roots and does well in bright diffuse light where it is allowed to dry between waterings.

Most common problem with this plant is over watering in low light. Keep this plant in good light and let it dry out a little more in the winter months.

Spider mites are also a problem for weak plants in low light. This [answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1840/best-practice-to-prevent-aphids-and-spider-mites/1842#1842) may prove helpful.