# Am I able to save this Meyers Lemon Tree?

Tags: diagnosis

I bought this lemon tree. I’ve wanted one for a long time and this one looked the best out of all the options at the store. I knew it was likely a suicide mission. However, is there anyway to save this? I’ve read other posts and it’s still green and has good drainage. I’m worried about the brown top though. Do I prune this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!! [image]

Answer (score 1):

Citrus bud new leaves from old wood quite readily.  The pot does seem to be quite large for the size of the trunk so I would expect to see the tree spending a lot of energy growing roots.

Patience is your ally in this case. Cut back the dead wood and see what happens over the next month or two.

Citrus are subject to deficiency diseases in alkaline soil and most peat based soil mixes will move closer to the ph of the water used.  If your water is ph 7 and higher you will need to use a citrus fertilizer with manganese and zinc sooner or later.  See [here](https://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/publication/ch142) for a very detailed review with pictures.

Citrus are also subject to [spider mite](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1840/499), [scale](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/18043/499) and [mealybug](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/8567/499) when kept indoors.  Examine the plant closely on a weekly basis